# Get wdio instance thread number

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I have a number of automated ui tests which run in parallel using the wdio maxInstances.
At the start of each test I generate a random / unique mobile number by doing the following:

```
07 - All numbers start with this number. 
Followed by a 9 digit number based on time & date - `new Date().getTime().toString().substring(4, 13)`
```

Unfortunately I'm facing issues where occasionally the timestamp is exactly the same. This is due to the test generating the mobile number at exactly the same time.
The second approach I tried was:

```
07 - All numbers start with this number.
Followed by a 6 digit number based on time & date - `new Date().getTime().toString().substring(4, 10)`.
Followed by a 3 digit random number - `Math.floor(Math.random() * 900 + 100);`.
```

This approach has resulted in less duplicated mobile numbers being generated, however I still occasionally get the same number generated.

Another approach I would like to try is to get the wdio instance thread/runner number and append it to the end of the mobile number. That way if a number is generated at the exact same time, the thread number will mean it will have a unique number. 
Is anyone able to shed some light on how to do this please.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about getting the thread number but we do a different thing. We try to assign unique number for each spec file.

Something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
    //list of features files that we have
    let listOfFiles = fs.readdirSync(process.cwd() + '/features');
    //Mapping one file with a unique number
    let fileMappedWithNumber = listOfFiles.map((file, index) => {
        const item = {
            file: process.cwd() + '/features/' + file,
            number: ++index
        }
        return item;
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(fileMappedWithNumber));
```

This code is placed in `onPrepare` hook. This variable `fileMappedWithNumber` can be assigned global and can be used throughout the code.

The `specs` in the `beforeSession` hook can be used to match with the file.

Comment: My onPrepare hook is in the wdio.conf. How can I call fileMappedWithNumber from there?

Comment: Hi .. define the `fileMappedWithNumber ` above the `export.config` and assign this variable to one of the global variable if needed. Like this: `let fMWN; export.config = { ... onPrepareHook{ the above code } ... beforeSession{ global.fMWN = fMWN} .... }`

Comment: Hi.. added our solution to your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58463916/is-it-possible-to-access-a-variable-declared-in-wdio-conf/58466351#58466351 try and let me know it works